# How to check and alter the Datatype in R in a function. (dynamic)

Tags: r, if-statement, dynamic, types, save

thanks for reading and helping.

I try to iterate over my Dataset with 1K plus Variables and check their datatype. Its for a neural network.
If it’s a Factor with levels it should change it to numeric
If it’s already a numeric nothing need be done.

I tried that but I have a weird interaction, which does not save the results. Maybe there is a smart way of doing that?

Dataset Example:

```
sex <- factor(c("male", "female", "female", "male"))
number <- c(1,2,3,4)
exampl<-data.frame(sex,number)
```

I tryed:

```
    ifelse(is.numeric(x), print("isnumeric"),ifelse(is.factor(x),"x" <-as.numeric(levels(x))[x],print("else")) )
```

Comment: Take the quotes off your `x`. At the moment you are saving to the character string `"x"`, rather than the variable `x`.

Comment: Thank you for your fast relpy,  
i tryed what you wrote. But it does not work on my end. I used the quotes to avoid reassigning the x. But the value type for the column is not saved. But i guss the quotes are one mistake. And there must be another. 

> str(x)
 num [1:643] 2 1 1 3 2 2 2 1 5 5 ...

> str(Model$F_Q06c)
 Factor w/ 9 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 1 1 3 2 2 2 1 5 5 ...

Comment: A vector (here `x`) can have only one class. So it is going to be either factor or numeric. Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for it. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback . I Edited my post and i hope its more clear now. If should add more informations pls let me know.